# Finding the sum of products from the product of sums (polynomials)

Tags: algorithm, polynomials, polynomial-math

Polynomials are usually written as a sum of powers (or various products of generators) and Google gives me lots of results how to get from that to the form that is a product of pure sums (the one where you can see where the polynomial vanishes):

> x^2 - 1 = (x + 1) (x - 1)

I'm looking for the other direction though, which is much easier, but still computationally expensive if done naively.

I have an array of n values that the polynomial vanishes on. Can I get the coefficients in n log n somehow?

Answer (score 1):

I doubt it. N log N is the theoretical known best asymptotical speed for polynomial multiplication. However, the problem seems to require hierarchical polynomial expansion by multiplying

```
step 1) x^2 + Ax + B = (x + a)(x + b), x^2 + Cx + D = (x + c)(x + d), ..., 
step 2) x^4 + Ax^3 + Bx^2 + Cx + D = (x^2 + Ax + B)(x^2 + Cx + D), ...
...
step log N/2)  (polynomial of order N/2) * (polynomial of order N/2)
```

When the size of the polynomial grows large enough, one can start use FFT based method, or Karatsuba before that. I would expect, that this method falls somewhere between the naive method of O(N^2), which will multiply a base polynomial (x+a) one by one with (x+b), (x+c)... and N log N, possibly to N (log N)^2.

Comment: Interesting, I would indeed like to see some material that address this issue on the fundamental algebraic level (rather than just for complex numbers).